# How to mark job as durable in Quartz .net?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

How to mark my `IJob` implementation as durable? I couldn't find any reference to this in quartz .net documentation and I do not use any xml job configurations. Shouldn't there be some kind of attribute like `PersistJobDataAfterExecution`, `DisallowConcurrentExecution` or boolean property in `IJob` interface?

Comment: have you checked the following [IJob Interface Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/4fc0f1b6-401d-a7aa-224c-c2fd34cec94e.htm)

Comment: @MethodMan, it has only one member, which is Execute().

Comment: if you do a search on this page for `Durability` have you seen this link http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

Comment: @MethodMan, yes I did, and I did try to apply Durability attribute to the IJob implementation class, but there seams to be no such attribute.

Comment: sounds like you have done your due diligence perhaps they have a support email or something where you can contact them.. I am all out of ideas myself..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var job = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>()
                    .WithIdentity(typeof(TestJob).Name)
                    **.StoreDurably(true)**
                    .Build();
```